# Concatenate list of strings into one string in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to concatenate a list of strings into one string that looks like this:

```
"53.4749673589885,-2.92261613132778:-2.92004169535242,-2.92004169535242:-2.92108733775938,-2.92108733775938"
```

From this

```
        [,1]     [,2]
[1,] -2.922616 53.47497
[2,] -2.920042 53.47325
[3,] -2.921087 53.47262
```

I can achieve the desired result using the code below, but I have thousands of rows making the use of something like this really inefficient.

```
paste0(lpool[1,][[2]],',',lpool[1,][[1]],':',lpool[2,][[1]],',', lpool[2,][[1]],':',lpool[3,][[1]],',', lpool[3,][[1]], collapse=',')
```

Does anybody have any advice as to how I can achieve the example string in an efficient way?

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: Do you have a matrix or a list of matrices?

Comment: @rawr `toString` could work, but I need to preserve the order of the rows as these are latitude/longitude pairs.

Comment: @akrun a matrix

Comment: I don't understand the rule, when to use the second column.

Comment: `paste0(sprintf('%s,%s', m[,1], m[,2]), collapse = ':')` maybe?

Comment: all of these are wronog based on the OP's expected output.

Comment: @Jaap's solution but slightly adjusted is perfect. `paste0(sprintf('%s,%s', m[,2], m[,1]), collapse = ':')`. Thank-you

Comment: @SamComber  It is still not the expected you showed there.

Comment: @SamComber thx, I forgot to switch the columns ;-). Anyway, as Akrun said: your expected output at the start of your question look different. Did you maybe make a mistake in that?